# Pausing one onClickListener while pressing another button

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

After pressing button2 ('dontKnowAnswer') I want to forbid button1 ('knowAnswerButton') to do any action untill setCurrentCard(); from inside runOnUiThread is called i've made global boolean state which does the job but it looks like really ugly solution to this problem is there any pattern on how to do that?

```
        knowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (currentPosition > mTestDeck.size()){
                    //TO DO
                    // END
            }
            if (state == true) {
                mTestDeck.correctAnswer();
                currentPosition++;
                setCurrentCard();
            }
        }
    });

    dontKnowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(currentPosition > mTestDeck.size()){
                //TO DO
                // END
            }

            myTextView.setText(currentCard.getBack());
            currentPosition++;
            state = false;

            new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    FlashCardActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setCurrentCard();
                            state = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, PAUSE_TIMER);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enable/disable **knowAnswerButton** view, so you will not need to keep a flag saving the state. To do that, just use `button.setEnabled(boolean)` method.

Notice that while button is not enabled (setEnabled(false)), user cannot click that button, so click event do not be fired.

```
dontKnowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(currentPosition > mTestDeck.size()){
            //TO DO
            // END
        }

        myTextView.setText(currentCard.getBack());
        currentPosition++;
        knowAnswerButton.setEnabled(false);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FlashCardActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setCurrentCard();
                        knowAnswerButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, PAUSE_TIMER);
    }
});

knowAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (currentPosition > mTestDeck.size()){
                //TO DO
                // END
        }
        mTestDeck.correctAnswer();
        currentPosition++;
        setCurrentCard();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use pattern Single Entry Point. Create your own StateClickListener that implement OnClickListener. Create static flag in this click listener and manage it inside you custom listener class.